# Regex ordering in R

Tags: r, regex

I would like to create a regex pattern using gregexpr in R, to match the following kind of text:

```
(SOME TEXT)R10043:(SOME TEXT)
(SOME TEXT)R34123:(SOME TEXT)R34254:(OTHER TEXT)
(SOME TEXT)R23123:(SOME TEXT)R34321:(MORE TEXT)
```

So far, I've tried this '[R]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[:]', but it doesn't work appropriately. For this text:

```
"\n\t\tperson.setRule( \"R10001:N\" );\n\t\tperson.setMessages( 
\"R10001:M0008:Bad customer.\" );"
```

The result using is:

```
[[1]]
[1]  35  44  81  89 166 174
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 7 7 7 5 7 5
```

Which is not what I meant.

Comment: What do you need to get as output? `R10043:`, `R34123:`, `R34254:`, `R23123:` and `R34321:`?

Comment: For each string I need to obtain the code(s)

Comment: Is `M0008:`  a code?

Comment: `R[0-9]{5}:` should work just fine. `[]` defines a character class ; if you just want to represent a single character, you can write it as is (expect for meta-characters which should be escaped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern consists of optional subpatterns, and can match an empty string. `[R]*`, `[0-9]*` match **0 or more** occurrences of the quantified subpatterns. Only `:` is obligatory as it has no `?` or `*` after it.

You may use the following code to obtain the "codes":

```
txt <- "(SOME TEXT)R10043:(SOME TEXT)(SOME TEXT)R34123:(SOME TEXT)R34254:(OTHER TEXT)(SOME TEXT)R23123:(SOME TEXT)R34321:(MORE TEXT)"
unlist(regmatches(txt, gregexpr("R\\d{5}:", txt)))
## => [1] "R10043:" "R34123:" "R34254:" "R23123:" "R34321:"
```

See [the R demo](http://rextester.com/QDSK53874) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x1jRsn/1).

**Details**:

- `R` - a letter `R`
- `\d{5}` - five digits
- `:`  - a colon.

Now, if your codes "overlap", ie. if you need to extract `M0008` (and in general, leave out `:` from those strings) use a PCRE regex:

```
unlist(regmatches(txt, gregexpr("[RM]\\d{4,5}(?=:)", txt, perl=TRUE)))
## => [1] "R10001" "R10001" "M0008"
```

See [R demo](http://rextester.com/KJJ74141)

The `(?=:)` is a *positive lookahead* that only checks if the text matches its pattern immediately to the right of the current location, and does not add the matched text to the match.

Comment: It worked as expected. +1 for the comprehensive way of explaining the subject.

Comment: And in case the codes start with any uppercase letter, `[RM]` can be replaced with `[A-Z]` or `[[:upper:]]`, and if these must be whole words, the regex should contain word boundaries - `"\\b[A-Z]\\d{4,5}(?=:)"` or `"\\bR\\d{5}\\b"`.